# Linux BIND server not updating A record

Tags: linux, bind

Good morning!

OK so we have DNS running on two domain controllers and we have forwarding going to a VIP.  Behind that VIP are IP's of two Linux BIND servers.  I had originally created an IP for a server in the DMZ using a public IP while I was doing some testing and everything went well.  I then deleted the A record on the Windows DNS server and created another one with a private IP.  This is where all the issues started.  Any time I want to ping that server from my machine or even from the BIND servers themselves I'll get the IP in the DMZ.  If I statically set the IP's of the DC's on my machine I'll get the correct IP when pinging FQDN.  I've tried setting an entry in /etc/hosts.  It allows the BIND servers to ping the right IP but nslookup against localhost still shows wrong IP.  I've bounced both BIND servers and flushed the DNS cache but no dice.  Perhaps someone can help me with this?  I sort of inherited this mess.  The previous engineer tried some sinkhole with these BIND servers (something I know nothing about) and I need to get this up and running in less than a month for go-live.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess that you are not trying to connect to the server from the same network. If this is the case, then you need to ensure that private IP is configured on your system.

Comment: I'm defintely on the same network just not on the same subnet as either the Windows DNS and BIND servers but I wouldn't see how that could be related.

Comment: please show us your config. maybe `cat /etc/hosts` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` are helpful.

Comment: the /etc/hosts file has an entry pointing the opposing BIND server, loopback IP, and I've also entered an entry for the domain in question.  Each BIND server pings the domain and it resolves to the right IP but the nslookup still fails to show the correct IP.

Comment: the /etc/resolv.conf has search suffix configured for three different internal domains (the domain in question is one of them).  the name server listed is just 127.0.0.1

Comment: ok, please show `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` or check if any `forwarders` are enabled or if `allow-recursion` is enabled for your local net or localhost.

Comment: options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        auth-nxdomain no;
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};

Comment: where do I check fowarders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually just solved this. I got curious and checked to see if our load balancer's DNS entries had a record for this and sure enough it did. I deleted it and recreated it correctly this time. Flushed the cache on both bind servers and did an nslookup and, sure enough, the record has the correct IP.

Answer (score 0):

add the following inside brackets of `options { ... };`

```
allow-recursion { 127.0.0.1; };
```

and maybe (I am not sure)

```
allow-query { 127.0.0.1; };
```

and restart bind. This will allow recursive queries from localhost.

Alternative:

add the following inside brackets of `options { ... };`

```
forwarders { <ip_dns1>; <ip_dns2>; };
```

while

- `<ip_dns*>` are the ip addresses of your dns servers or any other dns servers

Bind will then query those dns servers.

Comment: Tried this but no dice.  Still resolves to the wrong IP when doing an nslookup

Comment: @Lazaro ok maybe there is something else wrong. please try a `dig +trace domainquestion.tld`, maybe it sheds some light

Comment: I've actually just solved this.  I got curious and checked to see if our load balancer's DNS entries had a record for this and sure enough it did.  I deleted it and recreated it correctly this time.  Flushed the cache on both bind servers and did an nslookup and, sure enough, the record has the correct IP.

Comment: @LazaroRavelo great news that you solved it. You should add your own answer and accept it (after the wait period).